# Как мне сделать фиксированное соотношение сторон игры 16:9 в Unity WebGl?

Tags: unity3d, webgl, яндекс-игры

Я делаю игру для yandex игр в Unity. Я хочу что-бы моя игра имела соотношение сторон 16:9 независимо от экрана браузера. У меня сейчас игра растягивается на всю доступную область.
Тут что-то нужно менять в файле index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл вот такое решение, привязываешь скрипт к камере и устанавливаешь размеры по своему усмотрению. Если нужно будет другое соотношение сторон можешь просто поменять `float targetaspect = 16.0f / 9.0f;`
[Ссылка на скрипт](https://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.com/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html?m=1)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)